# How to resize and alternatively shift+resize?

Tags: autohotkey

Whilst devising a certain application, I came into the need to have two edit boxes in a small GUI window whereby you could <kbd>resize</kbd> the window and only size the first edit box, but a <kbd>shift+resize</kbd> would resize the second edit box instead.

[image: inline edit boxes]

*(Please ignore the thumbtack icons in my screenshots; it is an ontop-button placed there by DisplayFusion and doesn't affect this thread)*

My attempts have been using the `anchor.ahk` and `autoxywh.ahk` libraries, which automatically resize controls.  Here is my sample code along with a copy of autoxywh (you should be able to just paste and run it).

#### Using AutoXYWH.ahk library:

```
#noenv
#singleinstance force

apptitle := "ShiftResize"
 def_uiw := 212

Gui, +Hwnd%apptitle% +resize
Gui, +minsize%def_UIw%
gui, margin, 4
Gui, Add, Edit, vEdit1 HwndhEdit1 w100,
Gui, Add, Edit, vEdit2 HwndhEdit2 w100 x+4,
Gui, Show
return

GuiSize:
    If !pre_GuiWidth
        pre_GuiWidth := A_GuiWidth

    guicontrolget, edit1, pos
    guicontrolget, edit2, pos

    if(getkeystate("shift","P")){
        If (edit2w < 100) && (A_GuiWidth-pre_GuiWidth < 0)
            Return
        If (lastResize != "Edit2")
            lastResize := "Edit2", autoxywh("update_ctrl_info")
        autoxywh("w", hEdit2)
    }else{
        If (edit1w < 100)  && (A_GuiWidth-pre_GuiWidth < 0)
            Return
        If (lastResize != "Edit1")
            lastResize := "Edit1", autoxywh("update_ctrl_info")
        autoxywh("x", hEdit2)
        autoxywh("w", hEdit1)
    }

    pre_GuiWidth := A_GuiWidth
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

; =============================================================================
; Function: AutoXYWH
;   Move and resize control automatically when GUI resizes.
; Parameters:
;   DimSize - Can be one or more of x/y/w/h  optional followed by a fraction
;             add a '*' to DimSize to 'MoveDraw' the controls rather then just 'Move', this is recommended for Groupboxes
;   cList   - variadic list of ControlIDs
;             ControlID can be a control HWND, associated variable name, ClassNN or displayed text.
;             The later (displayed text) is possible but not recommend since not very reliable 
; Examples:
;   AutoXYWH("xy", "Btn1", "Btn2")
;   AutoXYWH("w0.5 h 0.75", hEdit, "displayed text", "vLabel", "Button1")
;   AutoXYWH("*w0.5 h 0.75", hGroupbox1, "GrbChoices")
; =============================================================================
;   Here is how GuiSize works with AutoXYWH (mod by toralf):
;http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7696&p=45882#p45786
;The first time Gui, Show executing, the GuiSize lable will be called. At that time then, AutoXYWH stores the initial x/y/w/h of Controls and GuiWidth/GuiHeight.
;Initial_GuiWidth := A_GuiWidth
;Initial_GuiHeight := A_GuiHeight

;GuiControlGet, Initial_Control, Pos, %ControlID%
;; Initial_ControlX
;; Initial_ControlY
;; Initial_ControlW
;; Initial_ControlH

;After that, when user resizing the Gui window, GuiSize lable will be called, AutoXYWH then calculates the changes of Gui Width and Height.
;Diff_GuiWidth := A_GuiWidth - Initial_GuiWidth
;Diff_GuiHeight := A_GuiHeight - Initial_GuiHeight

;Then, the new values:
;New_ControlW := Diff_GuiWidth + Initial_ControlW
;New_ControlX := Diff_GuiWidth + Initial_ControlX

;New_ControlH := Diff_GuiHeight + Initial_ControlH
;New_ControlY := Diff_GuiHeight + Initial_ControlY
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Release date: 2015-5-17
; Author      : tmplinshi (mod by toralf)
; requires AHK version : 1.1.13.01+
; =============================================================================
AutoXYWH(DimSize, cList*){       ; http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?t=1079
  static cInfo := {}

  If (DimSize = "update_ctrl_info") {
    For ctrlid, obj in cInfo
    {
        GuiControlGet, i, Pos, %ctrlid%
        cInfo[ctrlid].x := ix
        cInfo[ctrlid].y := iy
        cInfo[ctrlid].w := iw
        cInfo[ctrlid].h := ih
    }
    Return
  }

  For i, ctrl in cList {
    ctrlid := A_Gui ":" ctrl
    If ( cInfo[ctrlid].x = "" ){
        GuiControlGet, i, %A_Gui%:Pos, %ctrl%
        GuiControlGet, Hwnd, %A_Gui%:Hwnd, %ctrl%
        MMD := InStr(DimSize, "*") ? "MoveDraw" : "Move"
        fx := fy := fw := fh := 0
        For i, dim in (a := StrSplit(RegExReplace(DimSize, "i)[^xywh]")))
            If !RegExMatch(DimSize, "i)" dim "\s*\K[\d.-]+", f%dim%)
              f%dim% := 1
        cInfo[ctrlid] := { x:ix, fx:fx, y:iy, fy:fy, w:iw, fw:fw, h:ih, fh:fh, gw:A_GuiWidth, gh:A_GuiHeight, a:a , m:MMD}
    }Else If ( cInfo[ctrlid].a.1) {
        dgx := dgw := A_GuiWidth  - cInfo[ctrlid].gw  , dgy := dgh := A_GuiHeight - cInfo[ctrlid].gh
        For i, dim in cInfo[ctrlid]["a"]
            Options .= dim (dg%dim% * cInfo[ctrlid]["f" dim] + cInfo[ctrlid][dim]) A_Space
        GuiControl, % A_Gui ":" cInfo[ctrlid].m , % ctrl, % Options
} } }
```

#### Maestrith came up with this alternative:

```
#SingleInstance,Force
SetBatchLines,-1
Gui,+minsize230 +Resize +hwndmain
Gui,Add,Edit,w100 hwndedit1
Gui,Add,Edit,x+10 w100
ControlGetPos,x,y,w,h,,ahk_id%edit1%
SysGet,Border,32
SysGet,Caption,4
OnMessage(0xA1,"sizemove")
Gui,Show
return
GuiSize:
if(Resize="Left"&&offsetx&&A_GuiWidth-offsetx<=100){
    Gui,+minsize%A_GuiWidth%
}
if(Resize="Left"&&offsetx&&A_GuiWidth-offsetx>=100){
    GuiControl,1:Move,Edit2,% "x" A_GuiWidth-offsetx
    GuiControl,1:move,Edit1,% "w" A_GuiWidth+offsetw
}
if(Resize="right"&&offsetx&&A_GuiWidth+woffset>=100){
    GuiControl,1:move,Edit2,% "w" A_GuiWidth+woffset
}
if(Resize="right"&&offsetx&&A_GuiWidth+woffset<=100)
    Gui,+MinSize%A_GuiWidth%
return
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
return
sizemove(){
    global
    resize:=GetKeyState("Shift","P")?"Right":"Left"
    ControlGetPos,x,y,w,h,Edit2,ahk_id%main%
    ControlGetPos,xx,yy,ww,hh,Edit1,ahk_id%main%
    VarSetCapacity(rect,16)
    DllCall("GetClientRect",UPtr,main,UPtr,&rect),width:=NumGet(rect,8),height:=NumGet(rect,12)
    offsetx:=width-x+border
    offsetw:=ww-width
    woffset:=w-width
}
```

Neither of these solutions work perfectly.  If you play with the window and size and resize, shrink and grow using both <kbd>resize</kbd> and <kbd>shift+resize</kbd> the boxes will get out of whack.  For example, try to <kbd>resize</kbd> to grow `edit1`, then <kbd>shift+resize</kbd> to grow `edit2` to a nice length, then <kbd>shift+resize</kbd> to shrink `edit2`.  You get this, where `edit2` is run off the edge, or the second image where `edit1` goes off the edge with `edit2` not even visible:

[image: edit2 off the edge][image: both boxes out of whack]

To work perfectly:

- Each edit boxe needs a minimum size of `100px` and should not shrink below that size.
- Both edit boxes should stay visible - in other words, shrinking the GUI should never render one of the boxes not visible.
- <kbd>resize</kbd> should only resize `edit1`
- <kbd>shift+resize</kbd> should only resize `edit2`

Now, I realize I could just stack the edit boxes and forget about it, but that's not what I want to do.
[image: stacked edit boxes]

Now, [I have a thread on ahkscript.org](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7696), but the going is pretty slow, so I was hoping to draw some more attention here and hopefully find a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just Me on the Autohotkey forum solved this perfectly](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?p=46143#p46143):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetBatchLines, -1 ; important !!!

AppTitle := "ShiftResize"

MinSize := False
MarginX := 4

Gui, +Hwnd%AppTitle% +Resize
Gui, Margin, %MarginX%
Gui, Add, Edit, vEdit1 HwndhEdit1 w100,
Gui, Add, Edit, vEdit2 HwndhEdit2 w100 x+4,
Gui, Show, , %AppTitle%
Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

GuiSize:
   If (MinSize = False) { ; first call of GuiSize
      GuiControlGet, Edit1, Pos
      MinWidth1 := Edit1W
      GuiControlGet, Edit2, Pos
      MinWidth2 := Edit2W
      Gui, +MinSize%A_GuiWidth%x
      MinSize := True
      Return
   }
   Margin := A_GuiWidth - (Edit2X + Edit2W) - MarginX
   If GetKeyState("Shift", "P") { ; Edit2
      Edit2W += Margin
      If (Edit2W < MinWidth2)
         Edit2W := MinWidth2
      Edit2X := A_GuiWidth - Edit2W - MarginX
      GuiControl, Move, Edit2, x%Edit2X% w%Edit2W%
      Edit1W := Edit2X - MarginX - MarginX
      GuiControl, Move, Edit1, w%Edit1W%
   }
   Else { ; Edit1
      Edit1W += Margin
      If (Edit1W < MinWidth1)
         Edit1W := MinWidth1
      GuiControl, Move, Edit1, w%Edit1W%
      Edit2X := Edit1X + Edit1W + MarginX
      Edit2W := A_GuiWidth - Edit2X - MarginX
      GuiControl, Move, Edit2, x%Edit2X% w%Edit2W%
   }
Return
```